# problema con asincronias

Tags: javascript, promesas

Buenas estoy trabajndo con asincronias en JS el codigo es asi -->

```html
let variableGlobal=coso();

async function coso(){
    let datos;
        const res=await fetch("productos.json");
        
        const data= await res.json();
        variableGlobal=data;
        
        return data;
        
}
console.log(variableGlobal);
```

Como ven tengo una variableGlobal que quiero leerla por fuera de la sincronia
el valor obtenido[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen el array esta el tema que no esta solo tiene otro monton de datos lo que quiero obtener es solo el array y no logro encontrar la forma ya intente con variableGlobal.value no se por que lo que me interesa tener en la variableGlobal es solo los datos que aparecen marcados en la imagen,
Desde ya Saludos

Comment: ¿Viste [esta pregunta](/q/517230)? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tu variable global es y siempre será una Promesa. Toda función `async` devuelve una Promesa. Si quieres acceder al resultado de dicha Promesa, debes usar `then()`. No puedes sacar el resultado de procesos asíncronos fuera de su entorno asíncrono. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Las respuestas asincronicas devuelven promesas (Promise). Async y await es azucar sintactica que ocultan esas promesas.
Así que para usar el valor esperado de una promesa, tienes que usar await o, como con cualquier promesa normal, promesa.then(resultado => valor = resultado)

PERO, solo puedes usar await en funciones asyncronicas o en modulos.

Entonces en el ejemplo anterior lo puedes hacer de por lo menos 3 formas.

```
let variableGlobal1;
let variableGlobal2;
let variableGlobal3;

async function coso(){
let datos;
    const res=await fetch("productos.json");
    
    const data= await res.json();
    variableGlobal=data;
    
    return data;
    
}
//con una funcion de ejecucion inmediata asincronica
(async () => {
  variableGlobal1 = await coso();
  console.log(varliableGlobal1);  
}());
//definiendo una funcion auxiliar principal asyncronica y ejecutandola
const main = async function () {
  variableGlobal2 = await coso();
  console.log(variableGlobal2)
};
main();
//usar directamente la promesa que devuelve coso()
coso().then(res => {
  variableGlobal3 = res;
  console.log(variableGlobal3);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesites, tiene que hacer que la otra función sea asíncrona para poder ver informacion de lo contrario sale pending

```js
   async function coso() {
    const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/132/encounters");

    const data = await res.json();

    return {
      data
    };
  }
  const rest = async () => {
    const { data } = await coso();
    console.log(data);
  };
  rest();
```